# How to get GPS turn on-off events in android?

Tags: android, google-location-services

I have a simple broadcast receiver which receives GPS turn on/off. 
When I turn on GPS and I get `Improve accuracy dialog?`(Started appearing in android 8.0) provided by Android framework, I get `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED` receiver twice.

Below is my sample Receiver.

```
public class LocationServicesChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Intent action is "+intent.getExtras());

}
```

I have declared it in manifest as follow

```
<receiver
      android:name=".geofence.core.LocationServicesChangedReceiver"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Question:

- Is there any way I stop receiving multiple `onReceive()`
- Is there any other intent action to get GPS turn on/Off event.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any way I stop receiving multiple onReceive():

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"))
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location Providers changed");

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //You receive multiple data from more than one Provider, 
        // choose which one you want to use (GPS or NETWORK Provier).

        if (isGpsEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location Providers is GPS");
            // put your code in here to get data from GPS PROVIDER.
        }
        else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location Providers is Network");
            // put your code in here to get data from NETWORK PROVIDER.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But this part wont work when your app is killed.
My requirement is even if my app is in foreground/backgroud/killed, as user turns on GPS, i should perform certain actions.
The code you given willnot work when app is killed

Comment: if you want the application to run continuously in the background thread then run the function in the service.

Comment: For the same we have receivers... Please read and understand the problem. Location services are something that managed by OS. We dont need to put in seperate thread to run continuesly.